# Как добавить фото в сниппет ссылки wall.post VK.API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Вручную же можно менять фото сниппета, а через апи?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ техподдержки:

> К сожалению, так сделать не получится